# Converting utc offset value to time zone info in .NET Core 3.x

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Before I reinvent the wheel, I wanted to see if there was a built in way in .NET Core 3.1 to get a list of possible time zone names from an UTC offset value?

The `utcOffset` value is an `int` value that can be positive or negative. This is the `utcOffset` captured by a JavaScript client and sent to my ASP.NET Core 3.1 backend API. I just need to figure out a way to convert this to time zone name e.g. `Mountain Standard Time`, etc.

Here's my solution so far as I couldn't find a direct way to handle this but .NET Core 3.1 definitely gives us enough to work with.

```
public static string GetTimeZoneNameFromUtcOffset(int utcOffset)
{
    var timeZoneName = string.Empty;

    var possibleTimeZones = new List<string>();

    foreach(var tz in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
    {
        if(tz.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.UtcNow).TotalMinutes == utcOffset)
           possibleTimeZones.Add(tz.DisplayName);
    }

    if(possibleTimeZones.Count > 0)
        timeZoneName = possibleTimeZones[0]; // Not the best way but what I have so far

    return timeZoneName;
}
```

Comment: If you use that to persist for future use then use caution as each zone may change at different times, meaning, possibleTimeZones[0] may adhere to DST at a different time than possibleTimeZones[1], even though they share the same offset.

Comment: There is no way to do that consistently around the world. Many have tried and all have failed. Some countries have changed time zone offsets multiple times (more than twice) in a single year by dictatorial fiat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in capabilities will depend on the timezones registered on the system, and as commented by @Ross Bush, will also need to factor in DST.

For starters, you can try something like this with LINQ -- assuming hours but easy enough to switch to minutes:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> TimezonesByOffset(int offset)
{
    return TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().Where(x => x.BaseUtcOffset.TotalHours.Equals(offset)).Select(x => x.Id);
}
```

I'd also take a look into NodaTime, which has a pretty robust provider:

https://nodatime.org/TimeZones

Comment: I like the `LINQ` version better. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, it does need to be `TotalMinutes` if we were to match to a value coming from a `JavaScript` client.

Comment: Makes sense! Easy swap out from `TotalHours` to `TotalMinutes` in the clause, as I'm sure you can guess.